# scheme function tuples check

Tags: syntax, scheme

Ok, I am really really bad at scheme and I keep getting stuck on this function (watch it be a really easy fix). I am trying to write a function on whether or not a list input is a bag (a bag being a list of tuples where the first number in the tuple is the value and the second number is the cardinality, also each value should never be repeated and be sorted from least to greatest). This is what I have... syntax is probably horrible...

```
 (define (bag? qbag)
  (cond ((null? qbag) #t)
        (if(eqv? (pair? (car qbag)) #t)
           (baghelp (cdr qbag) (car(car qbag))))
        (else (#f))))

(define (baghelp qbag x)
 (cond((null? qbag) #t)
      (if(and(if (eqv? (pair? (car qbag)) #t))
             (if (< x (car(car qbag)))))
         (baghelp (cdr qbag) (car(car qbag)))
      (else(#f)))))
```

sample input output:

```
(bag? '((0 1)))
#f
(bag? '())
#t
(bag? '10)
#f
(bag? '((5 2) (4 3)))
#f
(bag? '((5 2) (7 3)))
#t
(bag? '((5 1 0)))
#f
(bag? '((5 5) (5 2)))
#f
```

Comment: Can you add example input and output?

Comment: Please use proper indenting. One cannot read the code of lisp-like languages without it....

Comment: @KarolyHorvath `s/ without it//` FIFY lol j/k /s

Comment: @uselpa input and output added

Comment: @Karoly Horvath is this better indenting? like I said I am really bad at scheme, give me c or java any day, if I could avoid it I would, lol

Comment: Why would the first example be `#f`?

Comment: @uselpa lol you know, I am not sure, its the instructors test data, I think he wants all the values, to be > 0, but he does not explicitly state that in his instructions and he does allow an empty tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your syntax is quite bad. The way you use of `if` inside `cond` and expressions like `(#f)` makes me think that you have avoided Scheme literature until now... really, read a good tutorial, that's a must.

Here's an example of how I would write this (more or less; I would factor out the repetitive uses of `(car bag)` and `(caar bag)` but this way it's probably more readable to you):

```
(define (bag? bag)
  (and (list? bag) (bag-help bag '())))

(define (bag-help bag last-val)
  (or (null? bag)
      (and (list? (car bag))
           (> (caar bag) 0)
           (= 2 (length (car bag)))
           (or (null? last-val) (< last-val (caar bag)))
           (bag-help (cdr bag) (caar bag)))))
```

This passes all your tests and has the additional contraints you mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @ uselpa thank you so much for your help, I have read some about it but for this class we are constantly changing languages and combined with the other courses I haven't had time to look into scheme as much as I'd like to, once the semester is over (yay winter break) I am planning on trying to go more in depth into it and hopefully improve my syntax greatly, I don't know that it is about scheme, but I just can't seem to grasp it, I need to find a really good step by step tutorial, I have just been using scheme.com for reference

Comment: The Little Schemer is a good intro. Simply scheme is a intermediate reference, and SICP is kind of a big deal.